# Copy and paste values only from multiple workbooks on a apecific worksheet in each workbook into one sheet in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, xlsx, xlsm

I am trying to copy and paste values only, from a specific range from multiple workbooks located in one folder that all has a worksheet named "summary". The code below I'm using Pastes the formatting and all, I only want to paste values. This is my current code:

```
Sub CopyRange()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim wkbDest As Workbook
    Dim wkbSource As Workbook
    Set wkbDest = ThisWorkbook
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Const strPath As String = "C:\Users\St\Desktop\ATP\"
    ChDir strPath
    strExtension = Dir("*.xls*")
    Do While strExtension <> ""
        Set wkbSource = Workbooks.Open(strPath & strExtension)
        With wkbSource
            LastRow = .Sheets("SUMMARY").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
            .Sheets("SUMMARY").Range("A2:AG" & LastRow).Copy wkbDest.Sheets("SHEET1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            .Close savechanges:=False
        End With
        strExtension = Dir
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

How do I change it so it only pastes values?

Comment: Great! whats the question then?

Comment: dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23937262/excel-vba-copy-paste-values-only-xlpastevalues

Comment: I want to only paste values, not the formatting, my current code pastes the formatting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make range of cells equal to another range of cells in different workbooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36312997/make-range-of-cells-equal-to-another-range-of-cells-in-different-workbooks)

Answer (score 0):

Just set the values equal:

```
With wkbSource
    lastRow = .Sheets("SUMMARY").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).row
    wkbDest.Sheets("SHEET1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = .Sheets("SUMMARY").Range("A2:AG" & lastRow).Value
    .Close savechanges:=False
End With
```

Note: You may need to tweak the first part (`...Offset(1,0).Value`) to be the same size as the origin information.  I think the below would work:

```
Dim infoToCopy As Range
Set infoToCopy = wkbSource.Sheets("SUMMARY").Range("A2:AG" & lastRow)
Dim firstRow As Long

With wkbSource
    lastRow = .Sheets("SUMMARY").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    firstRow = wkbDest.Sheets("SHEET1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    wkbDest.Sheets("SHEET1").Range("A" & firstRow & ":A" & firstRow + infoToCopy.Rows.Count - 1).Value = infoToCopy.Value
    .Close savechanges:=False
End With
```

Comment: where do I place the information for the first part?

Comment: Can you add your edits to my code so that I can copy and paste it please?

Comment: @Sapphire - You should be able to do that. It's pretty much exactly your code, just swap it out.  It will also help you learn how/where/when to edit the code.

Comment: I know. I'm trying and trying and I keep getting Runtime Error '424': Object required on this line : Set infoToCopy = wkbSource.Sheets("SUMMARY").Range("A2:AG" & LastRow)

Comment: Set infoToCopy = wkbSource.Sheets("SUMMARY").Range("A2:AG" & LastRow)

Comment: @Sapphire - To clarify, you are copying a *single cell* and want that value to populate the range from `A2` to `AG[lastRow]`?

Comment: No. I am copying a range of cells from A2:AG from multiple work books and want to copy and paste the all of those values into one sheet.

Comment: after one work book A2:AG is pasted on a master sheet, I want it to find the next empty row and paste the next work book A2:AG on the same master sheet and so on and so on