# Making range in one workbook equal to same size range in another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I was looking around at similar questions and most of what I was seeing was copy and paste.  This was not the approach I had in my head.  Then I stumbled on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36312997/make-range-of-cells-equal-to-another-range-of-cells-in-different-workbooks) and saw the answer by Tim Williams that SEEMED TO ME to be doing what I was thinking.  Basically its:

```
Workbook2.worksheet(1).Range("A1:D1")=Workbook1.worksheet(1).Range("A15:D15")
```

What I see in Tim's answer that makes me believe this method should work is the last line:

```
Destination.Resize(Origin.Rows.Count, Origin.Columns.Count).Value = _
                                                       Origin.Value
```

My actual portion of code is:

```
IndexCounter = IndexCounter + 1

'*****************************************
'LINE THAT IS NOT DOING ANYTHING
'*****************************************
MissingBook.Worksheets(DirectoryType).Range("A" & IndexCounter, MissingBook.Worksheets(DirectoryType).Cells(IndexCounter, LastCol)) = Source.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & varElement.Row, Source.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(varElement.Row, LastCol))


'check if file is downloaded
strNewFilename = DirectoryType & " " & varElement & ".*"
MissingFile = ExistingFile(SourceDir, strNewFilename)
MissingBook.Worksheets(DirectoryType).Cells(IndexCounter, LastCol + 1) = MissingFile
```

When I step through, all I am getting is the missing file value being inserted in the appropriate rows of the correct column.  The cells to the left remain blank. When I place the portion to the right of the `=` in the watch window.  I can see under value2 that all the in formation for each cell is there.

[image: Watch Results]

What am I missing/not understanding?

Comment: Shouldn't fix the problem, but side note, you should be explicit about the `.Value` part.

Comment: Bloody hell!  `.value` was the issue.  I swore when I ran this last night with .value it did not work..  May have many too many other changes at the same time.

Comment: Is this considered a TYPO and I should close the Question?

Comment: Is making a range equal to another range the better approach or is it better to copy and paste?

Comment: I am noticing that when I do this, string values containing numbers or dates are being recognized as their numeric value and being converted accordingly.  Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: Add a copy of that same line before the `.Value`  transfer, but instead of value you can use `.NumberFormat`. It would copy over the specific format for these cells, even if there are differences between them.

Comment: @JvdV Did not work.  Should this be a separate question?  In the initial sheet, the cells are formatted as general, but the numbers in them are stored as text.  I get a little warning of this when I hover cursor over the data when it a number like "0101.0700".  I get no warning for the date stored as text "Apr 1, 1994"

Comment: Well, I do think that it's a seperate question. Not following what the exact problem is without a clear example. So specify that in your question. I tried myself on a range with both text and numeric values and both the `NumberFormat`  and `Value` transfer just fine.

Comment: @JvdV I found a work around based on your previous comment.  I wound up setting the format of all cells to "@" instead of copying the exisitng format.

Comment: Then there you go =). Issues solved, another happy customer hehe